# Get child class name from parent with _CLASS_

Tags: php, oop

Basically what I'm trying to do is

```
class aParent{
    public function name(){
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}


class aChild extends aParent{

}

$child = new aChild();
echo $child->name();
```

I need to get `Child` instead of `Parent`. Is this possible? And why is it returning `Parent` in the first place, when I'm obviously calling the method from the `Child` class?

Comment: http://3v4l.org/7rTl2

Comment: @tereško: http://3v4l.org/kuXZp would be a more accurate example.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha .. yeah, you're right. I must have been damaged by the enormous complexity of this daunting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__CLASS__` is "compile" time constant, this is why it will be replaced with "Parent" at the very start of script execution [Magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

> this constant returns the class name as it was declared

to get current class name you can use [get_class](https://www.php.net/get_class) function

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) instead `_CLASS_`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the function [get_class($object)](http://php.net/get_class) in stead of creating and using a method inside the/each class.

But you can also create a method in the parent class and use  [get_class()](http://php.net/get_class) without any argument.